# Selenium: Use PageFactory or not?

Tags: java, kotlin, selenium-webdriver

I'm having some trouble agreeing with myself on wether or not to use PageFactory or not in my Selenium PageObjects.

As far as I can see, the point of using it is null safety, and that no WebElements are intialized before they're "used".

When I'm using Kotlin, I have to constantly null-check a WebElement intialized, like this:

From the PageObject class:

```
@FindBy(id = "boligLink")
val boliglink: WebElement? = null
```

The calling code (usually a Step Definition class):

```
boliglink?.click()

Or, something like:

return boliglink?.isDisplayed()
```

Are there any other advantages to this, compared to just using a try/catch - possibly abstracted - for each time the code accesses the WebElement?

Besides caching, but I don't think that's any point unless you access several elements more than once?

Wouldn't this do basically the same?

(The `getElementInElement()` is my function, for finding an element inside an element. It could just be `.findElementBy` blabla.)

```
return try { getElementInElement(element, By.cssSelector("[data-e2e-selector=boliginLink]")) }
    catch (e: NoSuchElementException) { throw NoSuchElementException("Couldn't find link to    boliginformasjon") }
```

Comment: imho, you should try/catch all driver calls.  Selenium's exceptions are very well designed and there are cases when you'd want to actually do something with and in the catch {} part.  (outputting reports, working with stale elements, etc...)  Also remember that the way current Page Objects are designed, they do not use webddriverwaits with explicit conditions.  These are necessary for site's that update the DOM via JS.  (implicit waits only go so far...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PageFactory` class resides among other classes such as `SlowLoadableComponent`, `FluentWait`, and `WebDriverWait` in the `selenium-support` library. Consider these classes as tools at your disposal; it's up to you whether you choose to use them or not.

Regarding `PageFactory`: Interestingly, Simon Stewart (Selenium project lead) admits that it was not the best idea to make it available to the public, as a result almost everybody is using it.
For reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyfUpOysIF8&t=1541s
https://twitter.com/shs96c/status/880809924607057920

There are many ways to work around PageFactory and still use Page Object model for abstracting your domain, but if you still intend to use it in Kotlin, then make sure to use `lateinit var` for your `WebElement`s:

```
@FindBy(id = "boligLink")
lateinit var boliglink: WebElement
```

And use `MutableList` instead of `List` to avoid `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` at runtime:

```
@FindBy(className = "image")
lateinit var companyNames: MutableList<WebElement>
```

Please notice you don’t need nullable `WebElement`s in order to make `PageFactory` work:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory

class HomePage(driver: WebDriver) {

    @FindBy(id = "boligLink")
    lateinit var boliglink: WebElement

    @FindBy(className = "image")
    lateinit var images: MutableList<WebElement>

    init {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I've never seen PageFactory as a prerequisite for the PO model. That would mean a complete misunderstanding about what the PO model is, I think. (Kind of how most Cypress people are mixing terms in a way that makes them appear as completely incompetent with regards to Test as a subject and profession.) I use it as an - in my opinion - "elegant" way to initialize WebElements in my PO classes. I didn't realize that I could just lateinit the variables instead of make them nullable. That's a clear improvement to the code imo.