# Selenium, Kotlin and PageFactory - initializing list of webelements

Tags: kotlin, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I'm trying to use PageFactory with Selenium, but for lists of elements I'm running into trouble.

I have this code:

```
@FindBy(css = "timeline-instances [data-e2e-selector=inst]")
lateinit var timelineInst: List<WebElement>

init { PageFactory.initElements(driver, this) }
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property timelineInst has not been initialized
```

In the same class, I also have this:

```
@FindBy(css = "[data-e2e-selector=postponeBtn]")
lateinit var btnWebElement
```

Which works fine.

Any ideas why it won't initialize a list of WebElements, when a single element works? I've tested by skipping PageFactory and just initializing it directly, and that works fine. So the problem is not with the element itself, at least.

If I replace the lateinit with null initalization, like this:

```
val timelineInst: List<WebElement>? = null
```

then it works. But I like using lateinit.

Comment: there's probably a different annotation for getting lists.  (That's a different method findElements instead of findElement...)  Haven't used POM so not sure what it might be.

Comment: There shouldn't be, from what I can find.

Comment: You can make a method in the page object.  Something like GetTimeLineInst... use findElements in there and return a List<WebElement>

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't help me use PageFactory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because List interface in Kotlin supports only read-only access as explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/#list).

What you need is MutableList, you can find a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75775997/3136143).